# TO-220 vs TO-3 advantages/disadvantages

Tags: power-dissipation, to220

Simple Question:

What are the advantages and disadvantages of TO-220 package vs TO-3 package in different applications/power requirements? Is there a best route?

Comment: Have you some specific transistors in mind? What denotes "better" for you?

Comment: The question you didn’t ask: why not move to SMD? TO-220 is active but declining by the day as the industry moves to SMD.

Comment: @winny For very high power parts, SMD is just nonexistent. TO-220 and TO-247 will remain common as long as we have applications that need to dissipate dozens to hundreds of watts. PCB heatsinks can only handle so much.

Comment: @Hearth Indeed, but the money spent on production cost of manually inserting TO-3 and screwing them to a heatsink, that could have been used on more and/or better silicon and decrease the losses in the first place. Salaries go up with inflation but silicon gets better and better every year.

Comment: @winny Well, most of my applications are hobby use and so I'm not too bothered to screw in a few screws here and there, but it is good to know this if I'm ever designing something commercially in the future. In this specific application, I'd be looking at 50-100W max power dissipation, do you think SMD would cut it?

Comment: @Klumpy7 Think first on how to reduce it to 5-10 W in the first place. No fans = less problems. Then check which transistors you have to choose from on the market. Factor in the risk of every manual intervention/job in the production line for both cost and risk of quality issues.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TO3 package is obsolete. It was introduced in [1956](https://sites.google.com/site/transistorhistory/Home/us-semiconductor-manufacturers/raytheon-part-one-2) along with the first germanium power transistor. To its credit, it survived to this day, which is quite the achievement.

Pin spacing was chosen so it would fit in existing vacuum tube sockets.

Its distinguishing features compared to other packages of the day were good heat transfer to a heat sink, while being hermetic and preventing water ingress. It was a huge upgrade compared to this:

[image]

But compared to modern packages it's terrible.

Even in high thermal conductivity materials like aluminium, in a sheet, heat diffusion works much better through the sheet (from one side to the other) than across (along the length of the sheet), because the former involves a much larger cross-section to conduct heat.

If you mount it on a L-bracket... the first drawback is you need a L-bracket and a bunch of extra screws, hardware, tapped holes and thermal grease, which adds cost. And heat has to travel along the wrong direction of the bracket to reach the heat sink. ([pic source](https://www.fischerelektronik.de/web_fischer/en_GB/heatsinks/A08/Die-cast%20heatsinks/VA/WP40301003AL/index.xhtml))

[image]

More modern packages like TO-247, TO-220, TO-3P are mounted directly on the heatsink, without the extra thermal resistance and cost of the L-bracket.

Now if you put the TO-3 on the heat sink [directly](https://fr.farnell.com/abl-heatsinks/520ab1000mb-t03/dissipateur-therm/dp/253728) then heat still has to travel a long way in the wrong direction in the flat aluminium piece behind the transistor.

[image]

Besides that, it has many other drawbacks:

- **There is no third pin, it's the transistor package itself.**

If it is exposed at the rear of the heat sink that's a short circuit or electrocution risk so you need a plastic cap. Even if you put a plastic cap, the screws are still live. If you see a heat sink at the back of an enclosure with a bunch of TO3s without plastic caps, chances are good every one of them is at a different voltage and any contact with a conductive object between the TO3s and the heat sink will result in something blowing up. If it's a high voltage device, keep your [fingers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNRacVQRgBc) away. It's just... bad.

[image]

You also need to connect this "pin" to your PCB via another cumbersome and fiddly part, like an eyelet washer or copper standoff with nuts and washers. Assembly is time consuming. In the old days wires were used, but that only works at low frequency due to inductance.

This is a [Marantz 250](https://www.usaudiomart.com/details/649507284-marantz-250-power-amplifier/images/2201922/) amplifier from 1973. Notice the custom made metal enclosure to protect exposed TO3s from short circuits...

[image]

- Depending on how the "third pin" (the package) is connected to the PCB, different thermal expansion versus the other two pins can create stress that will pop the pads off the board.
- Thickness of the heat sink plate or L-bracket is limited by the length of the pins
- It takes a ton of space on the PCB which can't be used for components
- High inductance due to long traces and wide pin spacing, so it can't be used for high speed switching
- Forces the board to be parallel to the TO3 mounting surface, which is inconvenient (most heat sinks are vertical for better convection, most boards are horizontal)
- Can't separate board from heatsink without desoldering it, which makes maintenance problematic
- More expensive than plastic packages, more expensive and labor intensive mounting.
- etc.

Overall, for high power, TO247 and TO3P are just better in pretty much every criteria. For low power, TO220 is much cheaper and easier to use. These packages have none of the drawbacks mentioned above.

Some advantages: TO3 being all metal can withstand higher temperatures and be hermetically sealed. It's also bigger, so it is still used to fit some hybrid circuits.

Comment: I agree that the main purpose of the TO-3 design was for heat transfer, but wasn't it also designed to fit the pin spacing in a tube [valve] socket? (another reason to consider it obsolete.)

Comment: Yes indeed! It's a 70 years old design (at least), about time for retirement

Comment: @bobflux I'm gathering new TO-3 products aren't made like they used to be. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgZhv.png) a snapshot from an old 1979 Philips databook. Something's changed, I guess. I didn't take a copy from my Mot book, but it has 0.8 where the Philips shows 0.6. Interesting. Today, seems like TO-3 is given as 1.5. I wonder what changed. I'm guessing the chips are made with smaller feature sizes now. But it's just a guess. I've no idea, really.

Comment: I've done transient thermal impedance measurement on transistors, and the size of the chip matters a lot: in a complimentary PMOS/NMOS pair, the PMOS has the bigger chip so it has lower heat density, more surface area to conduct it, which results in better thermals. Same for older FETs with larger chips. So I agree with your hunch about chip size. Also some TO-3 seem to be made of steel not copper...